# Blog posts not saving

Tags: web-server, apache-httpd

I am running an apache2 web server with my website bullyhomested.com and trying to add blog posts using rapidweaver and alloy3(elixir) but they don't show up. There is an example post that is supposed to populate and that doesn't show up either. I know that it's something to do with my server but I don't know what.

Comment: your question us not about the Raspberry Pi, so it is off topic here

Comment: @jsotola yet you didn't vote to close it.